# error : java.lang.InternalError: Failed remote launch: com.sun.jdi.CommandLineLaunch

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-9, jshell

I have to do a project using jshell java 9 feature. But when i'm launching in intellij with java 9 i have this error :

```
java.lang.InternalError: Failed remote launch: com.sun.jdi.CommandLineLaunch
```

What could be causing this?

Comment: Probably relevant: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8131029 - proposed workaround: add hostname to /etc/hosts with 127.0.0.1

Comment: It's works ! thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

***Update on October 26, 2017***

With `jshell 9.0.1` and `IntelliJ 2017.2.4` this seems to have been fixed.

One could get this working simply by typing `jshell` in the intelliJ's terminal as follows **::**

[image]